# how i can set the next version on xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I pushed the android mobile app (developed by **Xamarin.Forms** using PCL) with the following info on manifest:

[image]

I need to push next version, is that enough to update the following image on manifest?

Example:

> Version Number: 2  Version Name: 1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is basically enough. But the "Version number" for android must be an integer.

> versionCode — An integer used as an internal version number. This
>   number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent
>   than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions.
>   This is not the version number shown to users...

So just increase your "Version number" (+1) everytime you want to release your app and the playstore knows, that the version changed.

And for "version name":

> versionName — A string used as the version number shown to users. This
>   setting can be specified as a raw string or as a reference to a string
>   resource.

You can find detailed informations on the [android developer page](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html).

For Xamarin.Forms I recommend you to change also the version in the AssemblyInfo.cs - files in your projects (you can find those file in te Properties-Section):

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.1.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.1.0")]
```

This changes are not required, but with this changes, the assembly itselfs knows, that something changed (usefull for building, version check, and so on)

Comment: Hello, I've removed android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" from the manifest. When I try to archive a new build, it doesn't use my [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0")]. I can get that VersionCode doesn't match but at least versName should take the AssemblyFileVersion. What am I missing?